# Why should we pass args as args and not "*args"?

Tags: python

As I'm reading the Django documentation, I see this in the example:

```
from django.db import models

class HandField(models.Field):

    description = "A hand of cards (bridge style)"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 104
        super(HandField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I dont understand why the call to super is:

```
super(HandField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

whereas (coming from C programming) I thought it should be:

```
super(HandField, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
```

How comes?

Yes. And I'm not asking what mean "`*`" and "`**`" (link marked as a duplicate), I'm asking **why** it's not re-sent **without** the star = why it's re-sent to parent **with the stars**, which means to me: "dictionary of a dictionary". And my question is different from the duplicate link, and the duplicate link doesnt answer to my question.

Comment: Are you thinking that the `*` here idicates a pointer?

Comment: Yes. And I'm not asking what mean "`*`" and "`**`" (link marked as a duplicate), I'm asking **why** it's not re-sent **without** the star = why it's re-sent to parent **with the stars**, which means to me: "dictionary of a dictionary". And my question is different from the duplicate link, and the duplicate link doesnt answer to my question.

Comment: @OlivierPons: Why would you think it means "dictionary of a dictionary"? The answers in the duplicate explain exactly what calling a function with `*` and `**` arguments does, and it doesn't do what you're saying.

Comment: @OlivierPons see the bottom of the first answer: `Another usage...`. If that doesn't actually answer your question, please try to rephrase your question.

Comment: You call `foo(*args, **kwargs)` and not `foo(args, kwargs)` because `foo` accepts _some positional and keyword args_ and __not__ _tuple and dict_, because `args` is _just_ tuple and `kwargs` is _just_ dict

Comment: In a function definition they map  many parameters to single variables. Positional parameters to a tuple, named parameters to a dictionary. In a function call, they go backwards, they expand single variables out to multiple parameters.  A tuple -> positional parameters, a dictionary -> named parameters.

Comment: @OlivierPons: The duplicate does answer your question if you read a little further. The accepted answer first covers receiving `*` and `**`, then near the end covers _passing_ using `*` and `**`.

Comment: If you come from C then you should think of  `(*args,**kwargs)` as kind of a varags function. The `*args` means that `args` will a tuple holding every positiional argument and `**kwargs` means `kwargs` will be a dictionary with all keyword arguments. That's why when you call `super` you don't use the `*` and `**`. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you use `*`/`**` is to unpack the packed values you were given. When your class is initialized, it might be initialized with:

```
HandField(1, 2, 3, abc=4, xyz=5)
```

Because it receives the arguments using variable length positional (`*`) and dynamic keyword (`**`) arguments (to avoid needing to remember and deal with the specifics of what its parent class constructor receives), `args` is received as `(1, 2, 3)` and `kwargs` is `{'abc': 4, 'xyz': 5}`. If the parent class is defined with a `__init__` of:

```
def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3, spam=6, eggs=7, abc=None, xyz=None):
```

then calling `super(HandField, self).__init__(args, kwargs)` would pass the `args` `tuple` as `a1`, the `kwargs` `dict` as `a2`, and pass nothing at all for `a3` or other arguments. By [unpacking `args` and `kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), you convert back to individual positional and keyword arguments, so `a1` would get `1`, `a2` `2`, `a3` `3`, `abc` `4` and `xyz` `5`.

Basically, they're inverse operations; if you accept `*`, then the caller passes positional arguments one by one and they are "packed" into a single `tuple`, accepting `**` accepts individual keyword arguments "packed" as a single `dict`. If you want to pass them along the same way, you "unpack" them to make them individual arguments, not collections of arguments.